# Charm4py/charm++, GCC error when installing

Tags: raspberry-pi, gcc, g++

firstly I am going to explain the issue and at the bottom you'll find the question/-s.

I'm trying to install charm4py using pip/pip3/apt (all of em), after 1.5 hours it fails and I notice it's charm++ which fails to build and that

> g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
>
> ...
>
> Fatal Error by charmc in directory /tmp/pip-install-xqzy2dk8/charm4py/charm_src/charm/netlrts-linux-x86_64-tcp/tmp
>          Command g++ -DCMK_GFORTRAN -DCMK_GFORTRAN -I./../include -D__CHARMC__=1 -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -I../bin/../include -D__CHARMC__=1 -I. -O3 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector -fno-lifetime-dse -fPIC -c HierarchicalLB.C -o HierarchicalLB.o returned error code 4

I also get the following red colored error message in terminal,

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-install-xqzy2dk8/charm4py/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__); 
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n'); 
f.close(); 
exec(compile(code,__file__, 'exec')) 
"install --record /tmp/pip-record-ft7q83g9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-xqzy2dk8/charm4py/
```

So I, tried to install charm++ first manually. When building charm++ I get error as well it tells me that,

```
checking "C++ compiler as"... "g++  "   
checking "whether C++ compiler works"... "no"    
Cannot compile C++ programs with g++    
(check your charm++ version)      
*** Please find detailed output in tmp/charmconfig.out ***      
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'conv-autoconfig.h', needed by 'xi-     main.o'.  Stop.   
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raspberry/charm/multicore-linux/tmp'
Makefile:301: recipe for target 'headers' failed
make: *** [headers] Error 2
```

My gcc and g++ versions are `7.3.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)`

is the problem that I cannot download charm++ on Rpi 3B+ or lies the error with my gcc? Or maybe the problem is something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in Charm4py release 0.12.3 regarding building Charm++ and installing on Rpi 3B+. These will be fixed in the next release, so `pip3 install charm4py` should work then.

In the meantime, you can build and install charm4py for Rpi 3B+ like this:

Install cython and optionally numpy Python packages, using apt or pip.

Then, do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py
cd charm4py
git clone https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm charm_src/charm
python3 setup.py install
```

Hope this helps